# count length of class when style is display block

Tags: jquery

I need help below code is working fine, but I want it to add when li has style display: block with using `if(jQuery('li.individualadd').css('display') == 'block')` it doesn't work
please help how to make it work if li style is display block only

```
if (jQuery('li.gfield').hasClass('individualadd')) {
  // if (jQuery('li.individualadd').css('display') == 'block') {
  //   if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
      var count = jQuery('.individualadd').length;
      var extrafieldprice = 1 * 35;
      total = (count > 0) ? (total + extrafieldprice * (count)) : total;
  //   }
  // }
}
```

Below is the format that is working

```
if (jQuery('li.gfield').hasClass('individualadd')) {
  var count = jQuery('.individualadd').length;
  var extrafieldprice = 1 * 35;
  total = (count > 1) ? (total + extrafieldprice * (count - 1)) : total;
}
```

Comment: Can u add html code along with the question

Comment: can you create a fiddle with your related html code please .

Comment: @Shilpa You are using jquery class selector which internally uses `document.getElementsByClassName()`. This will return HTML collection. Try to print response `jQuery('li.gfield')`.